# IONIC | how do i set new page in the tabs?

Tags: ionic-framework, tabs

**Hello**

I have a problem with the links on my ionic app.
I'm trying to set new tabs but I'm having a problem with the links.

**tabs.html**

```
 <ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab [root]="tab1Root" tabTitle="test1" tabIcon="md-mail"></ion-tab>

  <ion-tab [root]="tab2Root" tabTitle="test2" tabIcon="md-contact"></ion-tab>

  <ion-tab [root]="tab3Root" tabTitle="test3" tabIcon="md-chatbubbles">

     <ion-tab [root]="tab4Root" tabTitle="test4" tabIcon="md-beaker"></ion-tab>
     </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

**tabs.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ListPage } from '../list/list';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = ListPage;
  constructor() {

  }
}
```

How do I add links to tabs 3 and 4?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab 3 & Tab 4 will have to link to new pages.  You will have to create these new pages FIRST. To create these pages, use following Ionic CLI commands:

```
ionic generate page Chat

ionic generate page Breaker
```

(documentation https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/generate/):

I **strongly** suggest using the CLI to create your page. When you use the generate parameter, it will scaffold out everything your page needs (including the exported module, css, html, etc.).  If you create the page manually, you might miss some of the valuable scaffolding that's needed with every page. You can download the ionic CLI using NPM.  https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/

**Then**, follow the exact same convention you see for Tab 1 and Tab 2.

For example, let's say Tab 3 will go to a page called *ChatPage*.  And Tab 4 will go to page called *BreakerPage*. Your **tabs.ts** will look like:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ListPage } from '../list/list';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';
import { ChatPage } from '../chat/chat';
import { BreakerPage } from '../breaker/breaker';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
})
export class TabsPage {

  tab1Root = HomePage;
  tab2Root = ListPage;
  tab3Root = ChatPage;
  tab4Root = BreakerPage;

  constructor() {

  }
}
```

Also fix your **tabs.html** page. It has two ending  for the last tab, in the example you provided.

Comment: It doesn't look like your new pages have been created. Ensure you've created the Chat and Breaker pages appropriately.  I've added instruction on how to do that to my answer above.

Comment: Thanks!! one last question:
How do i make the 4th page open first?

Comment: @RoeeBendor play around with <ion-tabs selectedIndex="2"> in your html file.  The selectedIndex value is 0 based, meaning selectedIndex 2 will make the 3rd tab active by default.